# Replace old image

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace

I'm using the "watermark" plugin to generate text on the image.

I have a button to generate the image with random text, so far all right, but if I click again, it adds the new image to the side, I wanted the previous image to be replaced by the current one. How can I do this?

http://brianium.github.io/watermarkjs/

Comment: Have you tried anything? Share us your [mcve]

Comment: Offtopic: whats the use of a watermark if its added clientside?

Comment: find img using jQuery and change img src via attr in event.

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
    $(".img-responsive").remove();
```

thank's for your time